# How to "flag" the equivalent of "export" to the compiler pre-modules?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, c++17

Imagine I've got the following files:

`simulate.h`:

```
#ifndef SIMULATE_H
#define SIMULATE_H

#include "my_data_type.h"

MyDataType Simulate ();

#endif
```

`simulate.cpp`:

```
#include "simulate.h"
// include lots of other things
// define lots of functions and new classes to solve sub-problems
// finally we define the "Simulate" function, which is the **only** thing we want to export.
```

Now, imagine that we have lots of header/cpp files pairs like above (with a tonne of functions/data types that aren't required outside of the cpp files).

Am I right in thinking that this creates unnecessary overhead for both the compiler and the linker?
As I understand it, the compiler can't know what won't be used by other object files, so this would create more bloated `.o` files and thereby slow down the linker, is that right?

I know that `modules` solves a lot of these problems in `c++20`, but is there some standard way around it in `c++17`?

I can think of one way that would seem to communicate to the compiler that the *introduced* functions/data types are not going to be reused: wrap them up in a `class`, put everything in the `private` section and expose only one method to the `public`. However, this is super hacky and ugly.

Comment: Unnamed namespace / static functions might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jarod42 pointed out in the comments, we can used unnamed/anonymous namespaces, whose contents are unreachable from other translation units ([N3797: 7.3.1.1](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft)):

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced
> by

```
inline /*opt*/ namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
using namespace unique;
namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

> where inline appears if and only if it appears in the
> unnamed-namespace-definition, ***all occurrences of unique in a
> translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this
> identifier differs from all other identifiers in the entire program.***

So we can use this to tell the compiler what's local to our translation unit:

```
namespace // Sub-problem stuff:
{
// ... classes
// ... functions
}

// Export stuff:
// ... classes
// ... functions
```

This way the compiler is only bound to the correct behaviour of the "exports", so can do things like remove some of the sub-problem functions that have been **inlined**.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, the compiler can't know what won't be used by other object files, so this would create more bloated .obj files and thereby slow down the linker, is that right?

Broadly speaking... no.

The code *has to be* in the .o files, because the code you do "export" uses it. Any code transitively used by the executable has to get compiled and stored in *some* object file. So it's going to have to be somewhere, and the compiler will have to read it and store it in the executable.

As for whether it slows down linkers, they're pretty good about finding the specific code they're looking for. I mean yes, some compilers may load the whole file into memory, so a bigger .o will take longer to load. But again, your "exported" function uses that code, so it still matters.

Comment: @Elliott: I don't understand what you're talking about. What gets put into .o files is *compiled code*. `std::min` is a template, and it doesn't get fully compiled until you *instantiate* that template (and then it gets "compiled" for each distinct instantiation). If you never use a template, it never gets instantiated, so the only cost is the cost of the compiler looking at code it never uses.